# Updating the UI of a Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to update the UI of a Viewcontroller (lets say A) which stacked below the current viewcontroller (lets Say B). I'm implementing as follows:

```
     BViewController.h

     @protocol BDelegate <NSObject>
        -(void)updateDelegate;
     @end

     @interface  BViewController: UIViewController{
           id<BDelegate> delegate;
      }
     - (void) setDelegate:(id)newDelegate;
     @end

     BViewController.m
     - (void) setDelegate:(id)newDelegate{
            delegate = newDelegate;
      }               


      - (void)updateList{
         //do something 
         [delegate updateDelegate];
       }


    A's viewcontroller 
    AViewcontroller.m
    -(void)deviceAddedDelegate{
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           update UI
       });
    }
```

The current view thats displayed is BViewController. AViewController is stacked below and when the user navigates back, he should pop the BViewController. This is when the UI updates will be seen. However AViewController's UI is not updated.

Comment: Are you setting the delegate anywhere?

Comment: Yes I do. When I push the new view controller. I set bvc.delegate = self; infact the delegate method is being called.

Comment: What happens if you move the UI updates outside of the async block?

Comment: It still doesn't update the UI if I move them out of the sync. It updates the ui elements, executing it on some background thread.

Comment: Sorry, it does update the UI? Or it still doesn't?

Comment: Just realized that the way you've got it in the stack, you probably want the delegate protocol on A, not B; B would then call the delegate method on A to update its UI. You'd also need to reference the instance of A inside B where you call the delegate.

Comment: try setting the delegate in B inside the prepareForSegue method of A